# WAMP Will Not Turn Green

Tags: windows-10, wamp

I just installed WAMP for the 1st time on my Windows 10 machine. I see no errors in the Apache or MySQL logs; I have changed the `httpd.conf` port to 8080 and attempted to connect via `localhost:8080` but still receive the error:

```
This site can't be reached
localhost refused to connect
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Doing `Apache --> Test Port 80` returns this message:

```
Your port 80 is not actually used.
```

netstat -aon | findstr :80

returns this:

```
TCP   192.168.3.22:49830   216.58.193.142:80  TIME_WAIT 0
```

(So is port 80 actually being used)?

---->I altered my httpd.conf file to use port 8080 as I could never get things working on port 80.  The command `netstat -aon | findstr :8080` does not return anything.

Does nothing being returned mean that things are functioning as they should?

Comment: `TCP   192.168.3.22:49830   216.58.193.142:80  TIME_WAIT 0` is an **outbound connection** to google.

Comment: @DavidPostill - my mistake I actually switched my port over to 8080 to try to get WAMP running - and that returns nothing when I netstat.

Comment: [This may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671456/wampserver-orange-icon/21678795#21678795)